# Catalina crashes whenever I open Safari, Chrome, Finder or other applications

Tags: macos, upgrade, crash, catalina

Recently I have upgraded my Mac to Catalina, and it crashes whenever I open Safari, Chrome, Finder or other applications.

I am not able to use any of my stuff and my laptop is lagging heavily.

Even Apple's Mail crashes when I click on Mail.

Comment: Please add some crash report...

Comment: [Catalina: After some hours various things start to crash and/or stop working \[closed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374271/) and [macOS Catalina crashing everytime](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374731/) cc:@klanomath